# Jenkins and Artifactory Integration

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I want to deploy the maven artifact to a folder inside Artifactory Repository through Jenkins. 
But we can choose the Artifactory repositories but how to specify the folder inside reposiotry where artifact has to be placed.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a maven build then you should not choose the path. The path should be taken from the POM of your build and the right coordinates of your artifacts. Maven is not flexible with his layout.